# How to reset disabled value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two select options boxes.based on first select option second select option is disabled. Suppose I'm select second select box value is setting that box. After I'm going to select first select box. second select box value is disabled. but not resetting second select box value.

**Code:**

```
<label class="item item-select">
    <span class="input-label">Purchase Type </span>
    <select  name="requiredType" ng-model="bid.requiredType" required>
        <option disabled="" value="">Select Purchase Type</option>
        <option>Partial</option>
        <option>Full</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label class="item item-select">
    <span class="input-label">Purchase Unit</span>
    <select  name="purchaseUnitType" class="form-control"
        ng-model="bid.purchaseUnitType"
        ng-disabled="bid.requiredType=='Full'"
        x-ng-change="checkUnitType(bid.purchaseUnitType)"                                                   required="required">
        <option disabled="" value="">Select Purchase Unit</option>
        <option>Kg</option>
        <option>Quintal</option>
        <option>Ton</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke an `ng-change` function to reset the value of second filter.

**JS**:

```
  $scope.reset=function(){
  $scope.bid.purchaseUnitType="";
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
 <select  name="requiredType" ng-model="bid.requiredType" required ng-change="reset()">
        <option disabled="" value="">Select Purchase Type</option>
        <option>Partial</option>
        <option>Full</option>
    </select>
```

**Working JSFiddle**:https://jsfiddle.net/m9oq9tqq/

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to associate a `ng-change` on the first select box so that when the option in the first select box is change or selected the second select box option is reset. For disable the same code works

HTML

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
   <label class="item item-select">
    <span class="input-label">Purchase Type </span>
    <select  name="requiredType" ng-model="bid.requiredType" ng-change='changeFirstSelectBox()' required>
        <option disabled="" value="">Select Purchase Type</option>
        <option>Partial</option>
        <option>Full</option>
    </select>
</label>
<label class="item item-select">
    <span class="input-label">Purchase Unit</span>
    <select  name="purchaseUnitType" class="form-control"
        ng-model="bid.purchaseUnitType"
        ng-disabled="bid.requiredType=='Full'"
        x-ng-change="checkUnitType(bid.purchaseUnitType)"                                                   required="required">
        <option disabled="" value="">Select Purchase Unit</option>
        <option>Kg</option>
        <option>Quintal</option>
        <option>Ton</option>
    </select>
</label>
</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.changeFirstSelectBox = function(){
       $scope.bid.purchaseUnitType = '';
   }  

})
```

Notice that i have just reset the value of second select box inside the function `changeFirstSelectBox ()`. FOr simplicity and further workarounds here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y83wk5zk/1/).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to reset the second dropdown selected value you need to add an [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) on your first dropdown.

updated HTML:

```
<label class="item item-select">
    <span class="input-label">Purchase Type </span>
    <select  name="requiredType" ng-model="bid.requiredType" required ng-change="vm.onRequiredTypeChanged()">
        <option disabled="" value="">Select Purchase Type</option>
        <option>Partial</option>
        <option>Full</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

JS

```
self.onRequiredTypeChanged = function(){
    $scope.bid.purchaseUnitType = null;
}
```